# Can I Force Kubuntu Installer To Use Nvidia Driver, Not Nouveau?

Tags: installation, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu, nouveau

Is there an alternate install routine for Kubuntu 12.04 that would force the installer to use the Nvidia driver rather than Nouveau?

I ask because I've installed KDE-Full on Ubuntu 12.04 and like it.  I may decide to install Kubuntu.

However, the kernel currently on the Ubuntu install images will cause a crash almost immediately after installation begins -- before Grub runs -- that appears to be triggered when X attempts to launch Nouveau.  Here, the machine locks up and requires a power toggle.

To install Ubuntu 12.04, I had to install 11.10, ensure the Nvidia driver was installed and Nouveau blacklisted, and then dist-upgrade to 12.04.

I don't want to do that if I decide to install Kubuntu. Hence, I'm looking for a way to get the installer to use the Nvidia driver. Or, an install method that avoids the entire issue until the Nvidia driver can be installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it use the nvidia proprietary driver, but you can force it *not* to use nouveau by selecting the "nomodeset" option during boot.

The Live CD allows you to press a key at boot-up then press F6 (if I recall correctly) to set boot options, and "nomodeset" should be one of them.

That should cause the Live CD to use a fallback VESA graphics mode.  It will look dodgy, but it should work, and once you have installed Ubuntu you can then install the nVidia driver.

Comment: Thanks, Neon.  If I use "nomodeset", does that mean the installed system will also use VESA when I reboot into it?

Comment: Ok, I found my answer [in this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) very good explanation of common kernel boot options and how to tell grub about them. Options used to boot the LiveCD do **not** percolate to the installed system.

Comment: On second thought, doesn't adding kernel options to the LiveCD (or an installed system) require that it get far enough along in the boot process to display the purple splash screen with the keyboard at the center bottom? This problem doesn't allow things to get that far.  You boot, and a few seconds later the screen is black and the machine is locked, including the keyboard.  I tried getting to that kernel option menu with the Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD.  No go. The crash happens before that.

Comment: It's a [kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42876).

Comment: Yes, if you don't get to the pre-boot screen with the keyboard icon at the bottom, this is not going to work unfortunately - sorry about that.  Hopefully this advice can still be of some use to others.

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same problem. Things I have done:
1) Booted with nomodeset option(pressed F6 and selected it).
2) Pressed Ctrl-Alt-F1
3) sudo -i
4) sudo apt-get --purge remove xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
5) sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
6) Reboot.
7) Now you should not select any options anymore. You may just boot(press enter and go ahead!).

I have met the same problem with linux mint 13 and with ubuntu 12.04. 1) I was not able to solve it in mint but 2) I have installed ubuntu 12.04 very fast, just followed steps 2-7 described above. Note: after installing the system to your hard drive you will have to follow these steps once more on your fresh system.
Conclusion:
So you can force Kubuntu 12.04 / Ubuntu 12.04 installer to use the official NVidia driver.
UPD: I hope you understand that I boot from a usb-stick.
UPD: After installing Kubuntu 12.04 I had to press **E** in grub and add **nomodeset** boot option near (quiet and splash), then press F10 to boot.
UPD: I have got it working with Linux Mint 13! You should follow the steps, install **nvidia-current** and then run **nvidia-xconfig**. That's it. Suggested by AlbertP and Ben on #linuxmint-help irc channel.

ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION: you can edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add blacklist nouveau , but i thought the hadware drivers tools took care of this